# AJAX update Wordpress comments count automatically

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm a real noob at AJAX and so I was wondering how I could make my comment numbers auto update using jquery and AJAX in Wordpress. Thanks for your help. Heres my jquery:

```
        <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            setInterval( "countnumbers();", 2000);

                countnumbers = function(){

                $('cite.commentcount').each(function(){
                    $(this).load('<?php get_permalink(); ?>, <?php echo get_comments_number(); ?>');
                }); 

                } // End countnumbers function

        });
        </script>
```

Heres my PHP:

```
    <a href="<?php the_syndication_permalink();?>" target="_blank" class="readstory"></a>
        <?php if(!is_single()) : ?>
        <cite class="commentcount"><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?></cite>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="comments"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
```